# How to use a file in a jar as javax.net.ssl.keystore?

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I'm trying to do something like

```
URL clientks = com.messaging.SubscriptionManager.class.getResource( "client.ks" );
String path = clientks.toURI().getPath();
System.setProperty( "javax.net.ssl.keyStore", path);
```

Where client.ks is a file stored in com/messaging in the jar file that I'm running.

The thing that reads the javax.net.ssl.keyStore is expecting a path to the client.ks file which is in the jar. I'd rather not extract the file and put in on the client's machine if possible. So is it possible to reference a file in a jar?

This doesn't work as getPath() returns null. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: The title is misleading.  It looks like you're asking whether you can get a File reference to a resource in a jar file; the System.setProperty call is irrelevant.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Still working on implementation, but I believe it is possible to load the keystore from the jar via InputStream and explicitly set the TrustStore programatically (vs setting the System properties).  See the article: [Setting multiple truststore on the same JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591281/setting-multiple-truststore-on-the-same-jvm)

Got it working!

```
InputStream keystoreInput = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream(<path in jar>/client.ks");
InputStream truststoreInput = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream(<path in jar>/client.ts");
setSSLFactories(keystoreInput, "password", truststoreInput);
keystoreInput.close();
truststoreInput.close();

private static void setSSLFactories(InputStream keyStream, String keyStorePassword, 
    InputStream trustStream) throws Exception
{    
  // Get keyStore
  KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());    

  // if your store is password protected then declare it (it can be null however)
  char[] keyPassword = keyStorePassword.toCharArray();

  // load the stream to your store
  keyStore.load(keyStream, keyPassword);

  // initialize a key manager factory with the key store
  KeyManagerFactory keyFactory = 
  KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());    
  keyFactory.init(keyStore, keyPassword);

  // get the key managers from the factory
  KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyFactory.getKeyManagers();

  // Now get trustStore
  KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());    

  // if your store is password protected then declare it (it can be null however)
  //char[] trustPassword = password.toCharArray();

  // load the stream to your store
  trustStore.load(trustStream, null);

  // initialize a trust manager factory with the trusted store
  TrustManagerFactory trustFactory = 
  TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());    
  trustFactory.init(trustStore);

  // get the trust managers from the factory
  TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustFactory.getTrustManagers();

  // initialize an ssl context to use these managers and set as default
  SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
  sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);
  SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);    
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been searching for the solution for a while, and all the other things I've seen looked too damn complicated :)

Comment: Nice work, should note however that you are using the keyStorePassword twice. As the keystore password and as the private key passphrase, and that is not always the case.

Comment: I added a new parameter, 'String keyPassphrase" and changed a line to keyFactory.init(keyStore, keyPassphrase.toCharArray());

Comment: @user252937.. today you are my savior.. I was looking for this solution on how to convert inputstream into a path. But your solution works like a charm!!!

Answer (score 8):

Here's a cleaned-up version of [user2529737's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17352927/365237), in case it helps. It has removed unneeded trust store setup and added required imports, parameters for keystore type and key password.

```
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.KeyStore;

public class PlainJavaHTTPS2Test {

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        final String KEYSTOREPATH = "clientkeystore.p12"; // or .jks

        // store password can be null if there is no password
        final char[] KEYSTOREPASS = "keystorepass".toCharArray();

        // key password can be null if there is no password
        final char[] KEYPASS = "keypass".toCharArray();

        try (InputStream storeStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(KEYSTOREPATH)) {
            setSSLFactories(storeStream, "PKCS12", KEYSTOREPASS, KEYPASS);
        }
    }
    private static void setSSLFactories(InputStream keyStream, String keystoreType, char[] keyStorePassword, char[] keyPassword) throws Exception
    {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keystoreType);

        keyStore.load(keyStream, keyStorePassword);

        KeyManagerFactory keyFactory =
                KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

        keyFactory.init(keyStore, keyPassword);

        KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyFactory.getKeyManagers();

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(keyManagers, null, null);
        SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: (I was thinking if I should make this its own answer or not, but upon reading [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299524/365237), I chose to have it as its own)

Answer (score 5):

You can get an `InputStream` to a resource in a jar file, but not a `File`.  If the "thing" that ultimately reads the keystore expects a `File` or a path to a file, your only option is to extract it to the filesystem.

Comment: Ok, thanks! That's what I have done in the meantime, and that works fine; it's just not as clean.