# Setting multiple truststore on the same JVM

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, truststore, jsse

I have an Java application running on a weblogic server. The application has two distinct modules which use SSL to connect to external web services - let's say module A and module B.

Module A - Built on Axis - Uses truststore A
Moudle B - Built on Spring-ws - Uses truststore B.

Module A is existing. Module B is being introduced.

I need to be able to set the truststore dynamically in the JVM based on which module is being invoked.

Due to some constraints I do not have the option
- to create a custom key manager.
- use one truststore

I tried to use System.setProperty im Module B codebase to set truststore. However it works only if Module B got invoked first. For example - Say 
I have a fresh restart of the JVM
then I invoke module A - it set's it's own truststore in the JVM
then I invoke module B - It fails - it's does not set it's own truststore in the JVM even though I have used System.setProperty method.

Am I missing something or it's just that System.setProperty doesn't override existing set values. If so what are my options here.

Comment: Why do you need two truststores? A truststore only tells you which CAs you can trust to authenticate the peer. Why would that be different per module?

Comment: Please check out this, it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793979/registering-multiple-keystores-in-jvm/

Answer (score 18):

You can load trusted key stores dynamically at runtime.

```
// load your key store as a stream and initialize a KeyStore
InputStream trustStream = ...    
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());    

// if your store is password protected then declare it (it can be null however)
char[] trustPassword = ...

// load the stream to your store
trustStore.load(trustStream, trustPassword);

// initialize a trust manager factory with the trusted store
TrustManagerFactory trustFactory = 
  TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());    
trustFactory.init(trustStore);

// get the trust managers from the factory
TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustFactory.getTrustManagers();

// initialize an ssl context to use these managers and set as default
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sslContext.init(null, trustManagers, null);
SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);
```

Watch out, because `SSLContext.getDefault()` would give you back the *default* context which you *cannot modify*, so you have to create a new one, initialize it then set this *new* context as the default.

The bottom line is that you *can* use any number of trust stores if you want to.