# AXIS Soap Call - use truststore only for selfsigned certifiates

Tags: soap, ssl, axis, truststore

I'm using Axis 1.4 in my client app to make SOAP calls. I am calling services over HTTPS. Some services use self signed certificates, others use certificates issued by a certificate authority.

I've used the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7593421/156477) to add the self signed certificate to my trust store.  My problem is that the truststore is being used for all calls - even the one's to servers that have a valid certificate from a CA.

Is there anyway to tell Axis to only use the truststore for servers that have self signed certificates ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's essentially the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256676/372643) (except that this was for client-certificate authentication).

You'll need to create your own socket factory class and pass it to axis using this property:

```
AxisProperties.setProperty("axis.socketSecureFactory",
    "com.example.MySSLSocketFactory");
```

(See [`org.apache.axis.components.net.SecureSocketFactory`](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/apiDocs/org/apache/axis/components/net/SecureSocketFactory.html).)

Since you already have a working `SSLContext`, instead of setting it as the default context, you need to create a `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory` from it and use this to create the socket within the Apache Axis socket factory.

Comment: Bruno:This a central configuration right?Is it possible to configure different socketfactories per request?

Comment: I would also like to configure per request. Does anyone know how to do this? @Cratylus did you find out how to do this?

Comment: @ademartini:I implemented my own socket factory class as the answer recommended