# Keystore not loading JKS file from within jar

Tags: java, classloader, loading

After hours of fighting with this, I'm starting to get really frustrated.

I have a JKS server file that I want to load from within the jar. Using FileInputStream works a treat as long as the file is outside the Jar, but as soon as I try to change that to getResourceAsStream it will just not take it, saying (No such file or directory).

This is how the project is distributed

```
ProjectFolder
-src
--package.name
---JKS File
---Class calling the resource retrieval and loading into the keystore
```

I think I have tried almost every combination of this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("jksFile.jks") I can think of.

I apologise in advance for not being more specific with the code, but I have literally lost count of what I have tried and what I havent.

HELP!

Thanks in advance

Comment: the method proposed in http://stackoverflow.com/a/17352927/420385 works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main ways of accessing resources inside the classpath, through the `Class` object, and through the `Classloader`, by getting `getResourceAsStream`.

Ultimately, the precise rules for implementing the lookup of the resource is class loader dependant. But most of it is clearly specified. The resource is looked up by name.

> The name of a resource is a '/'-separated path name that identifies the resource.

And, when exploring the classpath, the search order is also clear

> This method will first search the parent class loader for the resource; if the parent is null the path of the class loader built-in to the virtual machine is searched.  That failing, this method will invoke {@link #findResource(String)} to find the resource.

The `findResource` is the part that is implementation dependent. However, most Java classloaders are `URLClassLoader`s of some sort, and their implementation know how to explore the classpath entries (on the file system or inside JAR files - even remote ones) to resolve names as relative or absolute paths inside said-entries.

So, in a nutshell : you use `getResourceByName` to explore your classpath looking for a file by relative or absolute path in the class path.

The difference between `Class#getResourceAsStream` and `ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream` is that the `Class` version will interpret relative path as relative to the `Class`'s package, while the `ClassLoader` version will start at the root of the classpath.

So... Given the following project structure :

```
src
  name
    gpi
      file.txt
      Test.java
```

This Test.java works :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            // relative path from this class
    InputStream is = Test.class.getResourceAsStream("file.txt");
    byte[] content = new byte[4096];
    int length = is.read(content);
    System.out.println(new String(content, 0, length));

            // relative path from the root of the classpath
    is = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("name/gpi/file.txt");
    content = new byte[4096];
    length = is.read(content);
    System.out.println(new String(content, 0, length));
}
```

Be careful in details in the documentation thought, as

```
// This works : on the class object, absolute path are treated as "root of the classpath"
InputStream is = Test.class.getResourceAsStream("/name/gpi/file.txt");

//This does not work, because this looks actually at the root of the file system
InputStream is = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/name/gpi/file.txt");
```

If you try the combinations listed here as working, and they actually don't, then either you have a "funky" classloader (which should definitely not happen on a simple project), either your compiler / packager settings (maven or eclipse or whatever) are setup in a way that discards your JKS file from the compiled/packaged result (JAR).

In maven projects in general, Java classes belong to src/main/java directory, whereas properties, configuration, and JKS files usually belong to the src/main/resources directory. Depending on you exact maven setting, putting a JKS file inside the java directory may result in it being discarded from the actual, runnable classpath. So you should check that too.

Comment: Thanks for that! Finally got it working, my building setup was wrong, and it was leaving the JKS file out.

Comment: you have identical code in "this works" and "this does not work" sections?

Comment: @eis : fixed, sorry for that. Curious it stayed that way this long !

Answer (score 2):

If it is about a war file:

When building and running the project, the .class will not be in this location (/src) anylonger, it will go to WEB-INF/classes/..., so, maybe you could try to put your JKS File there, or make the reference from classes to src inside the getResourceAsStream().

Useful link for folder hierarchy of war file: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/Java-WAR-files.html

Comment: Thanks for that, unfortunately I'm not writing a web app, my JAR only has a META-INF folder, and thereafter the folder tree derived from the package name, including the JKS file, which is why I'm puzzled as to why it's not working :(

Comment: Also, if your keystore is buried in some package as you seem to indicate then `getResourceAsStream` will not be able to find it with just the file name.  Without a path the classloader will look for the keystore at the same level as the package root in the jar file.

Comment: Maybe this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941754/how-to-get-a-path-to-a-resource-in-a-java-jar-file

Comment: The jks file I'm trying to load is in the same package as the class doing the job of loading it, the application isn't complex enough to have a complicated file structure. The two files are literally one next to the other :(

Comment: Is your project a maven one?

Comment: try something like: .getResource("jksFile.jks").getFile(); I got this from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138574/java-path-to-truststore-set-property-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the jar contains the folder structure *under* `src` and that contains the compiled `.class` file(s) as well as or even instead of the source `.java` file(s) (which makes the directoryname `src` misleading):

- `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(String)`
  or other ways of getting the class like `MyClass.class` then `.getResourceAsStream(String)` 
  treats the resource-name as relative to the package = directory containing the class
- `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(String)` 
  or other ways of finding the classloader like `athread.getContextClassLoader()` then `.getResourceAsStream(String)` 
  treats the resource-name as relative to the root of the jar file, so you need `"package/names/jksfile.jks"`. 
  Remember package paths *in a jar* use slash whereas in Java source they use dot.

(Directories 'src' and 'bin' are generally used and useful when you put the source files under `src/package/names/MyClass.java` and the compiled files
in a mirror hierarchy `bin/package/names/MyClass.class`.)