# "mvn spring-boot:run" vs "java jar target/xxx.jar"

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, resourcebundle

I have two jks files under **src/main/resources** in my Spring Boot rest app

1. **Test1.jks** to make outbound call another rest api over https.
2. **Test2.jks** to enable https in this rest api.

I am setting path to resource file **test1.jks** using relative like below in Spring Boot entry point which has been working fine. These jks files is used to call an https service.

```
public class TestApp {

    static
    {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "TestApp.class.getClassLoader().getResource("test1.jks").getFile()");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", password);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",  "TestApp.class.getClassLoader().getResource("test1.jks").getFile()");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", password);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store=test2.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=test
server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:test2.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=test
server.ssl.key-password=test
```

When I run using `mvn spring-boot:run` everything works fine, however when I run it as executable jar `java -jar target/xxx-xxx-service-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` I am getting the following error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Could not find key store classpath:test2.jks
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.configureSslKeyStore(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.configureSsl(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:271)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.customizeConnector(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:248)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:147)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:157)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [test2.jks] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/Users/xxx/xxx/Himalay/xxx/xxx-xxx-service/target/xxx-xxx-service-0.1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar!/test2.jks
        at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:212)
        at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:175)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.configureSslKeyStore(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:288)
        ... 18 more
```

After commenting **application.properties** I found it cannot read even **test1.jks** when run using the executable jar command but runs fine with **mvn spring-boot:run**, how can I make it run using executable jar command?

**Note:** If I use absolute path to the jks files, it works fine with both the commands.

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344748/how-to-use-a-file-in-a-jar-as-javax-net-ssl-keystore

Comment: As @wemu comment point out, you can not use getFile() on resource which is embedded in Jar. Use inputstream

Comment: Isn't this the same issue as with your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713335/resource-filenotfoundexception-when-using-executable-jar-command-with-spring-boo

Answer (score -1):

Try this :
 `String filePath= Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("your-trust-store.jks").getFile();
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",  filepath);`