# Resource FileNotFoundException when using executable jar command with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, resourcebundle

To enable **https** in my spring-boot app I did the following.

```
@Bean
@Inject
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    final String absoluteKeystoreFile = ZenoTuringServiceApp.class.getClassLoader().getResource("test.jks").getFile();

    return (ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer factory) -> {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) factory;
        containerFactory.addConnectorCustomizers((TomcatConnectorCustomizer) (Connector connector) -> {
            connector.setSecure(true);
            connector.setScheme("https");
            connector.setAttribute("keystoreFile", absoluteKeystoreFile);
            connector.setAttribute("keystorePass", "test");
            connector.setAttribute("keystoreType", "JKS");
            connector.setAttribute("clientAuth", "false");
            connector.setAttribute("sslProtocol", "TLS");
            connector.setAttribute("SSLEnabled", true);
        });
    };
}
```

If I run it using **mvn spring-boot:run** it works as expected.

But when I run using the executable jar with `java -jar target/xxx-xxx-service-0.1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar` I get the FileNotFoundException.

```
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:993)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 18 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /private/var/folders/wl/xxx77_523z44yjdgx2y7xxxc217h/T/tomcat.8061417798873093914.8091/file:/Users/xxx/Work/Himalay/xxx/xxx-xxx-service/target/xxx-xxx-service-0.1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar!/test.jks (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getStore(JSSESocketFactory.java:433)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeystore(JSSESocketFactory.java:339)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:597)
```

Comment: You cannot reference a resource (inside a JAR) as a `File`. You **have to** use an InputStream. So `keystoreFile` should probably be located outside your JAR, since, apparently, Tomcat expects a path to a `File`.

Comment: Since you are executing this outside of Tomcat, you do not have "web" jars included. You need to include `Java EE from Tomcat` library.

Comment: this might be helpful https://kamwo.me/java-load-file-from-classpath-in-spring-boot/

Comment: thank you all, posted solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments above and this code helped me..

```
// support loading the JKS from the classpath (to get around Tomcat limitation)
private static File getTuringKeyStoreFile() throws IOException {
    ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("test.jks");

    // Tomcat won't allow reading File from classpath so read as InputStream into temp File
    File jks = File.createTempFile("ssl_keystore", ".jks");
    InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
    try {
        FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, jks);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
    }

    return jks;
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/robinhowlett/everything-ssl